# layout_centerInParent overrides layout_alignParentRight/layout_alignParentLeft in Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to align three views inside a RelativeLayout in such way that all three views are aligned center vertically. Then, I would like view "A" to be aligned to the left inside the RelativeLayout, view "C" to the right, and view "B" in between "A" and "C". The XML declaration looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ViewA
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        ... />

    <ViewC
        android:id="@+id/viewC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        ... />

    <ViewB
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/viewC"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewA"
        ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works perfectly fine on Android 4.2.2 and above, but not below (SDK 16). It seems android:layout_centerInParent overrides android:layout_alignParentLeft/android:layout_alignParentRight, as both "A" and "C" appear right in the middle of the layout, instead of aligned to the left and right respectively. Is there a way to set the vertical alignment using a different way inside a RelativeLayout?

Comment: you should do layout_centerVertical true to all the views and center_horizontaltrue to the middle one align left and right to the left and right image view

Comment: completely forgot about that attribute... problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` when you want to make it center vertical. Use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` instead.

Comment: as mentioned above, forgot about that attribute, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewA"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="A"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="B"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewC"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="C"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make your layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#ff00" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewC"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#00ff00" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#0000ff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```